# Calling forEach on an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Crockford's The Good Parts book tells me that JavaScript arrays are really objects.

Given that, why doesn't this work? (And am I weird for expecting it to?)

```
arr={0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d'}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, function(el){console.log(el)})
```

My thinking: If arrays are objects then presumably methods like `forEach` loop through an array's properties in ascending key order. (And through `call`, we can set the `this` that the method operates on.) I'm assuming that that's why `[].forEach.call(NodeList)` works.

Comment: You forgot the `length` property. `length: 4` https://jsfiddle.net/19to1oy6/

Comment: @squint oh wow, i did `arr.length = 4` and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @squint, please add your solution as a code snippet in an answer, it may be helpful to others.

Comment: Your reasoning is wrong. Arrays are objects, but that does not imply array methods are supposed to work for arbitrary objects. They do, though, because the spec says so (if the object is enough array-like).

Comment: *forEach* is specialised for Array objects, *for..in* is effectively a general *forEach* for all kinds of object.

Comment: @Oriol not sure it's an arbitrary object so much as one made to mimic an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your object does not have a `length` telling `.forEach()` how far to iterate.

This is important because JS arrays can be sparse, so it can't simply check for the existence of the property to determine if it should quit, and it would just keep incrementing, assuming that the next index may have a value.

So without the length properly set, the iteration fails on (or before, I don't remember) the first comparison.

In your example, to correctly represent the object as an array-like object, it could look like this:

```
var arr={0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', length: 4}
```

Now `.forEach()` will successfully iterate indices 0-3.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong. Arrays are objects, but that does not imply array methods are supposed to work for arbitrary objects. They do, though, because the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-createlistfromarraylike) says so:

> The `forEach` function is intentionally generic; it does not require
>   that its **this** value be an Array object. Therefore it can be
>   transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Of course, in order to work as expected, the object must be enough array-like. That means it must have a `length` property whose value is an integer larger than the array indices you want to iterate.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d', length: 4},
  function(el){ console.log(el); }
);
```

If you don't know the appropriate length beforehand, you may try

```js
console.log(Object.assign([], {0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d'}).length); // 4
```

Be aware that will call getters and skip non-enumerable properties. And once the array is built, you can call `forEach` directly on it instead of on the original object.

Alernatively, if your object is ordinary, `getOwnPropertyNames` is required to return the keys with the integer indices sorted first. Assuming all keys are integer indices,

```js
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames({0:'a', 1:'b', 2:'c', 3:'d'});
console.log(props.length ? +props[props.length-1]+1 : 0); // 4
```

If the array integer indices are not sparse, `props.length` could also be used.